# Opening the latest downloaded CSV file with Excel using AppleScript

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

I need to find a way to automatically open the last downloaded CSV file using excel

I've been trying to find some codes and adapt it to my needs but it won't work

The code below will open the latest file with numbers as expected. I can't change the default use of numbers for CSV files

```
tell application "Finder"   
    open last item of (sort (get files of (path to downloads folder)) by creation date) 
end tell
```

When I change to tell application "excel", it returns an error.

"Expected “,” but found “by”."

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Bear in mind that the `creation date` is not necessarily the date the file was created _on your system_ and, as such, doesn't equate to necessarily being the most recently downloaded file.  There's a _Finder_ metadata tag called `kMDItemDateAdded`, which holds the date a file was added to the folder in which is currently resides. Thus, the most recently downloaded file (to your _`~/Downloads`_ folder will have the most recent `kMDItemDateAdded` date value, up until the file is moved to another folder, or some other file is added to the downloads folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Finder's `open` command has a `using` parameter that lets you specify an application to open the file. i.e., code it this way:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFolder to folder (path to downloads folder)
    set latestFile to last item of (sort (files of theFolder) by creation date)
    open latestFile using (path to application "Microsoft Excel")
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to coerce the Finder item to a file path. This path reference can be opened with Excel

```
tell application "Finder"
    set latestFile to last item of (sort (get files of (path to downloads folder)) by creation date) as text
end tell
tell application "Microsoft Excel" to open latestFile
```